# How to assign specific modal to buttons in a Redux modal component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have built a modal component with Redux and Redux toolkit. This is how the component looks

initialState:

```
const initialsState = { isOpen: false };

export default initialState;
```

slice:

```
const modalSlice = createSlice({
  name: "modal",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setIsOpen: (state, action) => {
      state.isOpen = action.payload;
    }
  }
})

export const { setIsOpen } = modalSlice.actions;
export default modalSliuce.reducer;
```

selector:

```
const modal = (state: RootState) => state.modal;

export const modalSelector = createSelector(
  modal,
  (state) => state.isOpen
);
```

The modal component itself is quite simple. is just a fixed div with a background and children as props.

I need to use the same modal component for multiple cases with different content, but I'm unsure how to associate each button with the correct modal. When I click on a button, it always opens the first modal instead of the one associated with that button. How can I ensure that each button opens the intended modal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a single boolean state value that all modals are referencing you should store discrete state for any modal reference that is being toggled.

Example:

Modal slice

```js
export const initialsState = {
  isOpen: {}
};

const modalSlice = createSlice({
  name: "modal",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setIsOpen: (state, action) => {
      state.isOpen[action.payload.id] = action.payload.isOpen;
    }
  }
})

export const { setIsOpen } = modalSlice.actions;

export default modalSlice.reducer;
```

Selectors

Update/modify the selector to [take an extra parameter](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#q-how-do-i-create-a-selector-that-takes-an-argument), a modal id value in this case.

```js
const modalSelector = (state: RootState) => state.modal;

const isOpenSelector = createSelector(
  [modalSelector],
  (modal) => modal.isOpen,
);

export const modalIsOpenSelector = createSelector(
  [isOpenSelector, (state, id) => id],
  (isOpen, id) => isOpen[id]
);
```

To toggle a specific modal's `isOpen` value, dispatch the `setIsOpen` action with a modal id and open status.

```js
dispatch(setIsOpen({
  id: "modalA",
  isOpen: true
}));
```

```js
dispatch(setIsOpen({
  id: "modalA",
  isOpen: false
}));
```

To open a specific modal, use the updated/modified `modalIsOpenSelector` function and pass in the modal id parameter.

```js
const isOpen = useSelector(state => modalIsOpenSelector(state, "modalA"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Oliver I see, probably something trivial/minor. Do you happen to have the ability to create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of what you are working with that we could inspect live?

Comment: You right! I am very stupid and I apologize to you. Instead of creating a constant using the useSelector, I was distructuring the isOpen from the state xd.

Comment: `const { isOpen } = useSelector(state => modalIsOpenSelector(state, "modalA"));` This is what I was doing. Thank you very much for your answer